# Epsilon Delta Limit

Tags: real-analysis

I need to prove that $\lim_{x \rightarrow 3} x^2+5x+2 = 26$ using the epsilon delta definition.

I know $|f(x)-L|$ works down to $|x+8||x-3|$ but how do I use that going forward?

Thanks!

Comment: try this $|x+8| = |x-3 + 11| \le |x-3| + 11$

Comment: hmm, would you be able to elaborate?

Comment: $|x+8||x-3| \le (|(x-3)| + 11)|(x-3)| < (\delta + 11) \delta < 11 \delta $

Comment: thank you, but how is $(\delta + 11)\delta$ < $11\delta$?

Comment: woops!! sorry ... looks like i made error ... i was supposed to put the values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $|x-3|\leqslant1$, then $|x+8|\leqslant12$. Hence, for every $\varepsilon\gt0$, $|x-3|\leqslant\delta$ with $\delta=\min\{1,\varepsilon/12\}$ implies that $|f(x)-f(3)|\leqslant\varepsilon$.